# Font Awesome Icons are not displaying correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little problem with my Navbar icons. I'm trying to put my Instagram and YouTube icons, but they don't show up. When I click the link, I go to youtube/instagram page, but they are not displaying in the navbar.

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: #313840;
}

nav img {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.social-media-icons {
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #313840;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #313840;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="social-media-icons">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fas fa-instagram" color="white" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fas fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
      </label>
    <img src="mmt-white.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Onde Atuamos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Servicos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Depoimentos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">comecando</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacte-nos</a></li>
      <li2><a href="#">Acessar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the social media icons are part of the Font Awesome Brands font family.

Change the mark up from `fas` to `fab`

```
<div class="social-media-icons">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fab fa-instagram" color="white" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fab fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
```

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  height: 80px;
  background: #313840;
}

nav img {
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.social-media-icons {
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #313840;
  color: #fff;
  height: 40px;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #313840;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Navbar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="social-media-icons">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/mmtuniversity_oficial/" class="fab fa-instagram" color="white" target="_blank"></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCuf2KhhA8Ub3hcSgfaziiDw" class="fab fa-youtube" target="_blank"></a>
    </div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <label for="check">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" id="btn"></i>
          <i class="fas fa-times" id="cancel"></i>
      </label>
    <img src="mmt-white.png">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Onde Atuamos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Servicos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Depoimentos</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">comecando</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contacte-nos</a></li>
      <li2><a href="#">Acessar</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Down voter explain your down vote. This answers the question.